Downloading ERA5-Complete Reanalysis through CDSAPI results in Error-43. How to fix?
I am using flex_extract to send requests with CDSAPI to get ERA5 Complete Reanalysis Data. I can get data on 2018/08/09 with the area 74/-24/9.875/60.375 but changing the date or the area results in the following error. Does anyone know what the issue is and how I could fix it?
Error

roughly 1/3 of the data is not there, try cutting down the list of parameters and then increasing 1 by 1 to see?  it seems that some combination of levels, times or variables is not compatible.

where is the code that causes this error ?     the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
